# What is the airplane type in this formation seen above Eugene, Oregon?

Tags: aircraft-identification, turboprop, trainer

[image]

This flight of 2 flew by my house in Eugene, Oregon recently. I assume they're military pilot trainers but I am having trouble coming up with an ID.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: Thanks for the comments and links Redd Herring and YMB.  I had been leaning towards the A29 (EMB 314) and your posted photo of the EMB 312 looks good to me Redd.  I looked at Texans too and even though there were several canopy changes none matched my planes.                                                      The info on Military Tech pretty much cinches it.  They are based at EUG and I live on a 3 mile final to Ry34.  I'm a former controller at EUG and don't recall working these aircraft there so am guessing these are fairly recent acquisitions.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! I put this on the answer you posted but I'll put it here as well in case it gets deleted. If you think an answer is correct you should press the green tick to mark it as accepted rather than post another answer yourself. If you haven't already done so, I'd recommend taking our [tour] and read the [help] so you can see how this site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look very much like [Embraer EMB314 Super Tucanos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embraer_EMB_314_Super_Tucano)

Comment: I think the canopy and tail don't match.

Comment: @ymb1 Perhaps, but it might just be to do with the angle of the photo. The other candidate is the [AT-6 Texan II](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_T-6_Texan_II), but that seems to match rather less well.

Comment: This is [as close to the angle as I could find](https://www.avionews.com/en/item/1151379-laad-2013-senegal-purchases-three-embraer-a-29-super-tucano-aircraft-video.html/). A different dorsal fin and the presence of ventral fins (similar sun angle).

Answer (score 12):

They are most likely [Embraer EMB 312 Tucanos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embraer_EMB_312_Tucano). Military Tech, Inc. has [at least 10](https://prijet.com/owner/MILITARY%20TECH%20INC) registered in Eugene. Here is one in a similar paint scheme:

[image: EMB 312 on ramp]
<sup>[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:FAC2257_Embraer_Emb.312_Tucano_Colombian_Air_Force_(7501447362).jpg)</sup>

Comment: Here are photos for [one of those](http://www.airport-data.com/aircraft/N461EY.html) registered in OR.

Comment: Wow what are they doing with 10 of those planes in Eugene?  Do the hippies know?  (Real question, the first I mean)

Comment: Military Tech is a local group that buys and refurbishes surplus military aircraft.  When I worked at EUG (5 years ago) they were doing mainly helicopters.  It looks like they're expanding to fixed wings.